# How to find and print specific character in bash

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, find

I have file like:

```
AA,A=14,B=356,C=845,D=4516
BB,A=65,C=255,D=841,E=5133,F=1428
CC,A=88,B=54,C=549,F=225
```

I never know if in the row missing A,B,C or D value. But I need to transform this file like:

```
AA,A=14,B=356,C=845,D=4516,-,-
BB,A=65,-,C=255,D=841,E=5133,F=1428
CC,A=88,B=54,C=549,-,-,F=225
```

So if any value missing print just `-` mark. My plan is have the same number of columns to easy parsing. I am prefer awk solution. Thank you for any advice or help.

My first try was:

```
awk '{gsub(/[,]/, "\t")}; BEGIN{ FS = OFS = "\t" } { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~ /^ *$/) $i = "-" }; {print $0}'
```

But then I notice, that some values are missing.

EDIT:

From my header I know that there is value A,B,C,D,E,F...

Comment: what have you tried so far? it might be possible with awk by defining `,` as delimiter and iterating over all columns..

Comment: Please see edited. My first try was in awk.

Comment: thanks for adding your attempt, can you clarify if you want your output as `tab` separated or `comma` separated?

Comment: In my first try was tab separated, but I really do not mind. We can keep comma.

Comment: If two columns never appear together on the same line, their order can be undefined (e.g. `A=1,B=2,D=3` and `A=4,C=5,D=6`). What should be the output in such a case?

Comment: I would like to pre-define number of column - so output would be: A=1, B=2, -, D=3 and A=4, -, C=5, D=6.

Comment: So you know the A, B, C, D in advance? If not, how do you know that C comes after B? In other words, why is `A=1,-,B=2,D=3` and `A=4,C=5,-,D=6` invalid?

Comment: Sorry my fault - I have header of file which tells me order,A,B,C,D,E,F etc.. Thank you for good point.

Comment: @Geroge: Then please update the question with the information.

Comment: What does `From my header I know that there is value A,B,C,D,E,F...` translate to wrt your input? If there's something in your real input that you haven't shown us in your sample input then obviously you need to edit your sample to include that so you don't waste everyone's time having us come up with solutions to a problem you don't have. Maybe the thing that's missing will explain, for example, how you know to add `B=` if that field is missing from every line!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat file.txt
AA,A=14,B=356,C=845,D=4516
BB,A=65,C=255,D=841,E=5133,F=1428
CC,A=88,B=54,C=549,F=225

$ perl -F, -le '@k=(A..F);
   $op[0]=$F[0]; @op[1..6]=("-")x6;
   $j=0; for($i=1;$i<=$#F;){ if($F[$i] =~ m/$k[$j++]=/){$op[$j]=$F[$i]; $i++} }
   print join(",",@op)
   ' file.txt
AA,A=14,B=356,C=845,D=4516,-,-
BB,A=65,-,C=255,D=841,E=5133,F=1428
CC,A=88,B=54,C=549,-,-,F=225
```

- `-F,` split input line on `,` and save to `@F` array
- `-l` removes newline from input line, adds newline to output
- `@k=(A..F);` initialize `@k` array with `A`, `B`, etc upto `F`
- `$op[0]=$F[0]; @op[1..6]=("-")x6;` initalize `@op` array with first element of `@F` and remaining six elements as `-`
- for-loop iterates over `@F` array, if element matches with `@k` array element in corresponding index followed by `=`, change `@op` element
- `print join(",",@op)` print the `@op` array with `,` as separator

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

You haven't specified how to obtain the header information, so in the following script, the @header array is populated directly.

`%to_idx` hash maps the column names to their indices (A => 0, B => 1 etc.).

Each lines is split into fields, each field is compared to the expected one (`$next`) and dashes are printed if needed. The same happens for missing trailing fields.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @header = qw( A B C D E F );

my %to_idx = map +($header[$_] => $_), 0 .. $#header;

open my $IN, '<', shift or die $!;
while (<$IN>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /,/;
    print shift @fields;
    my $next = 0;
    for my $field (@fields) {
        my ($name, $value) = split /=/, $field;
        print ',-' x ($to_idx{$name} - $next);
        print ",$name=$value";
        $next = $to_idx{$name} + 1;
    }
    print ',-' x (1 + $#header - $next);  # Missing trailing fields.
    print "\n"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution in [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr)

```
@(do
   (defstruct fill-missing nil
     strings
     (hash (hash :equal-based))

     (:postinit (self)
       (each ((s self.strings))
         (set [self.hash s] "-")))

     (:method add (self str val)
       (set [self.hash str] `@str=@val`))

     (:method print (self stream)
       (put-string `@{(mapcar self.hash self.strings) ","}` stream))))
@(repeat)
@  (bind fm @(new fill-missing strings '#"A B C D E F"))
@{label},@(coll)@{sym /[^,=]+/}=@{val /[^,]+/}@(do fm.(add sym val))@(end)
@  (do (put-line `@label,@fm`))
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr missing.txr data
AA,A=14,B=356,C=845,D=4516,-,-
BB,A=65,-,C=255,D=841,E=5133,F=1428
CC,A=88,B=54,C=549,-,-,F=225
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN {                                  
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc" # order for for(i in a)
    for(i=65;i<=90;i++)                  # create the whole alphabet to array a[]
        a[sprintf("%c", i)]              # you could read the header and use that as well
}
{
    split($0,b,",")                      # split record by ","
    printf "%s", b[1]                    # printf first element (AA, BB...)
    delete b[1]                          # get rid of it
    for(i in b) 
        b[substr(b[i],1,1)]=b[i]         # take the first letter to use as index (A=12)
    for(i in a)                          # go thru alphabet and printf from b[]
        printf "%s%s", OFS, (i in b?b[i]:"-"); print ""
}

awk -v OFS=\, -f parsing.awk tbparsed.txt
AA,A=14,B=356,C=845,D=4516,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
BB,A=65,-,C=255,D=841,E=5133,F=1428,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
CC,A=88,B=54,C=549,-,-,F=225,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
```

It prints "-" for each letter not found in the record. If the data had a header, you could `split` to 2-D array `b[NR]` and change the `for(i in a)` to `for(i in b[1]) ... printf ... b[NR][b[1][i]] ...` and if you don't need the static first column, remove the first `printf` and `delete`.

Comment: Here's a little bit different version of this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398986/how-to-preprocess-and-load-a-big-data-tsv-file-into-a-python-dataframe/39399727#39399727